# mod_auth_form and proper redirection after login

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, redirect, mod-auth

Using the Apache module **mod_auth_form**, when a user tries to access a URL and is 'interrupted' by the form based login, how do I pass on the original URL to the html form or to the `AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation` directive, so I can redirect the client - upon successful authentication - to the URL where they wanted to go to.

I can add an `action="/index.html"` parameter to the form and redirect the user accordingly, but users will reach the login page from several URLs.

I didn't find any information on dynamically setting the value of `AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation`. Is there a way to do this with Apache 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

I am redirecting the user to the login page by specifying an error document for status code 401: `ErrorDocument 401 /my/login/page.html`. The login page will pop up whenever a user tries to access a protected resource (unless you use session and he's already authorized). After successfully logging in, the user is redirected back to the target URL by the apache. Therefore, I don't use `AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation` directive.

A more complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/buxxi/mod_auth_form-sample) (I am not the author).